# How to create Celery custom logging

Tags: python, celery

I have a custom python logging working. I want to build a celery custom logging, based on workers. I went through the Docs but couldn find a hint. Anyone can suggest me one such method to do so?

Comment: The final outcome i am planning is to have a different log files created for each worker. Which should be retrieved in the html to have view based on workers. I felt this will help me to monitor in a better way? –

Comment: Take a look at flower https://github.com/mher/flower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you want different log files for each worker do you mean for each worker node or for each pool worker process?

If it is for each node, that is already supported. Do `celery worker --help` for more info.

> -f LOGFILE, --logfile=LOGFILE
>                           Path to log file. If no logfile is specified, stderr
>                           is used.

If you are using supervisord for running your workers, you can use `stdout_logfile` and `stderr_logfile`

If you want separate logfile for each pool worker process, can you explain why? Note that pool worker processes will keep changing if maxtasksperchild is set to limit the number of tasks executed by a process. You will need to figure out how you want to relate each worker process to a log file in this case.